# Trying to replace columns of zeros array with datetime64 values

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to test out this method before I implement it in my code (so please ignore the horrible variable names) and honestly I'm not sure why I'm getting the values that I am. At the bottom is a screenshot from the shell terminal and let me run you through what I have done:

I have an array `X`, which has the shape `(105215,)` and is basically a single-column, thousand-row array containing `datetime64` values.

I also have an array `ZZ` which is a zeros array with dimension `(105215, 6)`.

Now when I try to replace the first column of `ZZ` with all the row values of `X`, I get values like `[16436., 16436., 16436., ..., 18627., 18627., 18627.]` in the first column of `ZZ` now.

Basically my question is: how can I get the original `datetime64` values instead of these ones?

[image: Shell Code]

Comment: Pay attention to the `dtype` of each array.  What is `X.dtype`?  `ZZ.dtype`?  Writing a `datetime64` value to a `float` array will not change that array to `datetime`.